# Implementing Aws Map in react Ui getting Uncaught ReferenceError: _wrapNativeSuper is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, maplibre-gl

I am trying to Implement Maps in my React website , I am not sure why map is not rendering in my web and getting - Uncaught ReferenceError: _wrapNativeSuper is not defined this error , here is my code to implement map in Ui (using Maplibre-gl)

```
Mapcomponent.js:
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import maplibregl from "maplibre-gl";

const Map = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    //.parissss test
    const latitude = 48.8566;
    const longitude = 2.3522;
    const apiKey =
      "API key";
    const mapName = "Demomap";
    const region = "ap-south-1";
    const map = new maplibregl.Map({
      container: "map",
      style: `https://maps.geo.${region}.amazonaws.com/maps/v0/maps/${mapName}/style-descriptor?key=${apiKey}`,
      center: [longitude, latitude],
      zoom: 13,
    });
    return () => map.remove();
  }, []);
  return <div id="map" style={{ height: "400px" }}></div>;
};

export default Map;
```

```
Route.js:
import Dashboard from "views/Dashboard.js";
import SendRequest from "views/SentRequest";
import CreateEmployee from "views/Create-employee";
import Userprofile from "views/UserProfile";
import Map from "views/Map/Map"

var routes = [
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    icon: "nc-icon nc-tap-01",
    component: <Dashboard />,
    layout: "/admin",
  },
  {
    path: "/create-employee",
    name: "Create Employee",
    icon: "nc-icon nc-tap-01",
    component: <CreateEmployee />,
    layout: "/admin",
  },
  {
    path: "/request-sent",
    name: "Verification Request",
    icon: "nc-icon nc-tap-01",
    component: <SendRequest />,
    layout: "/admin",
  },
  {
    path: "/user-profile",
    name: "User-profile",
    icon: "nc-icon nc-tap-01",
    component: <Userprofile />,
    layout: "/admin",
  },
  {
    path: "/Map",
    name: "Map",
    icon: "nc-icon nc-tap-01",
    component: <Map />,
    layout: "/admin",
  },
];
export default routes;
```

```
index.js:
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "assets/scss/paper-dashboard.scss?v=1.3.0";
import "assets/demo/demo.css";
import "perfect-scrollbar/css/perfect-scrollbar.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css";

import AdminLayout from "layouts/Admin.js";
import Login from "login/login";
import ForgotPassword from "ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword";
import SignUp from "SignUp/SignUp";
import Verification from "Verification/Verification";
import Otp from "Otp/Otp";
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { login } from "action";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { EmailProvider } from "EmailCOntext/EmailContext";

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_REGION,
    userPoolId: process.env.REACT_APP_USER_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: process.env.REACT_APP_USER_POOL_WEB_CLIENT_ID,
    domain: process.env.REACT_APP_DOMAIN,
  },
});

const initialState = {
  isSignedIn: JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("isSignedIn")) || false,
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      updateAuthStatusInStorage(true);
      return {
        ...state,
        isSignedIn: true,
      };
    case "LOGOUT":
      updateAuthStatusInStorage(false);
      return {
        ...state,
        isSignedIn: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
});

const updateAuthStatusInStorage = (isSignedIn) => {
  sessionStorage.setItem("isSignedIn", JSON.stringify(isSignedIn));
};

function App() {
  const isSignedIn = useSelector((state) => state.isSignedIn);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleSignIn = () => {
    dispatch(login());
  };

  return (
    <EmailProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login onSignIn={handleSignIn} />} />
          <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUp onSignIn={handleSignIn} />} />
          <Route path="/forgot-password" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
          <Route path="/verification" element={<Verification />} />
          <Route path="/otp" element={<Otp />} />

          {isSignedIn ? (
            <>
              <Route path="/admin/*" element={<AdminLayout />} />
              <Route
                path="/"
                element={<Navigate to="/admin/dashboard" replace />}
              />
            </>
          ) : (
            <Route path="/*" element={<Navigate to="/login" replace />} />
          )}
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </EmailProvider>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

and my package.json

```
package.json
{
  "name": "paper-dashboard-react",
  "version": "1.3.2",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^5.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
    "ag-grid-community": "^30.0.2",
    "ag-grid-react": "^30.0.2",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.3.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.2",
    "chart.js": "3.9.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "maplibre-gl": "^3.3.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.5.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.4",
    "react-chartjs-2": "3.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.9.0",
    "react-notification-alert": "0.0.13",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-select": "^5.7.3",
    "reactstrap": "8.10.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "sass": "1.62.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",
    "compile-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/paper-dashboard.scss src/assets/css/paper-dashboard.css",
    "minify-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/paper-dashboard.scss src/assets/css/paper-dashboard.min.css --output-style compressed",
    "map-sass": "node-sass src/assets/scss/paper-dashboard.scss src/assets/css/paper-dashboard.css --source-map true"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "svgo": "3.0.2",
    "fsevents": "2.3.2",
    "chokidar": "3.5.3",
    "@babel/core": "7.18.6"
  }
}
```

I am trying this in react admin paper dashboard .I need to implement AWS maps in React Website . I am searched lot about this I am not able to find solution.Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

yes, this package.json file changes Worked.Able to rendered maps in my webThe above package.json is wrong, below is the correct order especially this order

```
"browserslist": {

   "production": [

     ">0.2%",

     "not dead",

     "not op_mini all"

   ],

   "development": [

     "last 1 chrome version",

     "last 1 firefox version",

     "last 1 safari version"

   ]

 }
```

For this order in package.json worked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).